# I cannot get the sum to calculate. I'm not even sure my logic is correct

Tags: java

I believe I may need to use for instead of while, I am unsure on how fix this. When I try to research this all I can find is in relation to "sum of arrays" My sum keeps coming out to equal 10 although I have declared the values. Can someone help? Thanks

```
public class OnlinePurchases {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO code application logic here

  String sName = " ";
  int nChoices = 0;
  int nChoice1 = 249;
  int nChoice2 = 39;
  int nChoice3 = 1149;
  int nChoice4 = 349;
  int nChoice5 = 49;
  int nChoice6 = 119;
  int nChoice7 = 899;
  int nChoice8 = 299;
  int nChoice9 = 399;
  int nSum = 0;
  final int SENTINEL = 10;
  int nCount = 0;

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("Please enter your name : ");
  sName = input.nextLine();

  System.out.println("BEST PURCHASE PRODUCTS \n");
  System.out.println("1.   Smartphone $249");
  System.out.println("2.   Smartphone case $39");
  System.out.println("3.   PC Laptop $1149 ");
  System.out.println("4.   Tablet $349");
  System.out.println("5.   Tablet case $49");
  System.out.println("6.   eReader  $119");
  System.out.println("7.   PC Desktop $899");
  System.out.println("8.   LED Monitor $299");
  System.out.println("9.   Laser Printer $399");
  System.out.println("10. Complete my order");

  System.out.println("");

  System.out.print("Please select an item from the menu above : ");
  nChoices = input.nextInt();

  while (nChoices != SENTINEL) {
   System.out.print("Please select another item from the menu above : ");

   nCount++;

   nChoices = input.nextInt();

   if (nChoices == 1) {
    nChoices = nChoice1;
   } else if (nChoices == 2) {
    nChoices = nChoice2;
   } else if (nChoices == 3) {
    nChoices = nChoice3;
   } else if (nChoices == 4) {
    nChoices = nChoice4;
   } else if (nChoices == 5) {
    nChoices = nChoice5;
   }
  }

  nSum = nSum + nChoices;
  System.out.println("Price of Items Ordered : " + nSum);
  System.out.println("Total Items Ordered : " + nCount);
 }
}
```

Comment: you will have to explain what is happening?  What is the input and what is the output?

Comment: You loop until the user enters 10, then end the loop. At that point, the number is `10` and you add it to your initial sum `0` to get `10`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop is fine.

Your problem is occuring because when a choice is selected you are not actually adding to your nSum variable. So when it comes to printing the sum out you are actually printing

```
nSum = nSum + nChoices = nSum = 0 + 10
```

This is why you are constantly getting the value 10.

To fix this replace your nChoices if statement with

```
if (nChoices == 1) {
    nSum += nChoice1;
} else if (nChoices == 2) {
    nSum += nChoice2;
} else if (nChoices == 3) {
    nSum += nChoice3;
} else if (nChoices == 4) {
    nSum += nChoice4;
} else if (nChoices == 5) {
    nSum += nChoice5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the variable nChoices to check for the number that is entered. When you want to stop the program, 10 is the last number that is entered so 10 is what is added to nSum. To fix this you should first check for the first input before you enter the while loop and then check the input at the end of the while loop so that if 10 is chosen it won't go through the loop again. Also, under each if/else if statement you should use:

```
nSum += nChoiceWhatever //"Whatever" being the number correlated to your prices
```